# How to import external JARs from one project to another?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have created a new IntelliJ Project, and I want it to have JAR dependencies like I have in another project.

Is there a way to Export-Import / Copy-Paste JAR dependencies from one IntelliJ project to another **without using POM**?

Thanks.

**Optional Solution:**

```
1. Open <old-project>/.idea/libraries folder and <new-project>/.idea/libraries folder.
2. Make sure to enable the displaying of hidden files (in Win7, go to control-panel--> Folder Options --> View, and select the 'Show hidden files...')
3. Copy all XML files exists in .idea/libraries from the old project to the new one.
4. Make sure that each xml points to the right location of Jar. (In case of relative link)
5. Open the <old-project>.iml and <new-project>.iml, and copy all <orderEntry type="library" name"..."/> elements.
6.  Restart your new project.
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a way to do this from within IDEA, but under your project folder you can find a directory called `.idea/libraries` that has a series of XML files, one for each external dependency. You should be able to copy these between projects and thus "share" dependencies.

Comment: Thanks. 

Already tried it but: 

1. It didn't work (maybe there is a need to update the workspace.xml as well),

2. I hoped to find a way to do it from the IntelliJ itself

Comment: So, it seems that copying the .idea/libraries + updating the <project>.iml file (just copy all orderEntry elements) will add the jars into the new project. Still looking for more IntelliJ way to do that